# Source code or detailed explanation of “WKS” virtual memory compression algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, memory, memory-management, compression, lossless-compression

I asked this question on cs.stackexchange.com, but I haven't received any helpful replies -- only some comments stating that my question was off-topic, so, I'm asking it here, as per the StackExchange guidelines :

I've been trying to find information on various program data virtual memory compression algorithms that are in the "WK" family of algorithms. So far, I've been successful with the "WKdm" compression algorithm ( see [here](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/usenix99/full_papers/wilson/wilson.pdf) and [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.22.5/iokit/Kernel/WKdm.h.auto.html) ). The other algorithm that I'm interested in is a variation on the "WKdm" algorithm called the "WKS" algorithm. The paper in which it was first introduced can be found [here](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~barua/matt-compress-tr.pdf). The problem is that the paper does not describe the algorithm in any detail and just gives a very brief high-level overview of some major differences with the "WKdm" algorithm without any in-depth technical description. I have only found one other reference in the literature to the "WKS" algorithm. I've also contacted the author of the paper in which the algorithm was first mentioned but I've yet to receive a response.

Does anyone know the details of the "WKS" algorithm?

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

jdb2

NOTE : The only other reference I could find to the "WKS" algorithm can be found [here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1023833.1023872?download=true) in section 9 on page 288 :

"We explored the following three compression techniques, all of which roughly satisfy the  above  criteria:  (i) LZO, a  modern implementation of the Lempel-Ziv dictionary-based compression algorithm [29]; (ii) WKdm, which uses a combination of dictionary-based and statistical methods and is characterized by a very small dictionary size [34] and (iii) WKS, a modified version of WKdmthat  supports  in-place  compression  and  de-compression,  without having to copy data to an intermediate buffer [28]."

Note that reference "[28]" above is circular as it points back to the paper already linked to in my post in which the "WKS" algorithm was first mentioned.